Horror movie about a killer in mental institution, before 2006?
I watched this movie on TV 10 years ago,and it was set in a mental institution. I remember there being a killer, who wore a black cover or nylon and killed people in the mental institution. I also recall a scene where he captured one of the doctors maybe, not sure, and electrocuted him. If someone could find that movie I would be very grateful. Not very sure about the country and language, because it was voiced in my home language, but maybe US.
PS: It might even be from the 90s when I think about it, but not sure.

Do you remember anything else about the plot? Any other characters?

Don't remember much else. I think the killer was pretending to be a phantom or something like that, and when he did the electrocution, the man was strapped to a chair and I think the killer used a defibulator to his head. Also if I remember correctly,the main character was a male patient inside the asylum, and there was a nurse he befriended.

Sounds like madhouse but the provided information is not much to be sure.

@AnkitSharma That's it, I think this is the movie I've been trying to remember. It seems I completely forgot what it was about. Thank you for the answer.

Confirmed as a duplicate of Identify horror movie taking place in a psychiatric hospital.
